# where azure snapshots are stored with this script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

I found this blog post

https://www.techmanyu.com/automate-disk-snapshots-azure/

And the author showes this script.

```
$clientID = "<client id>"
$key = "<client secret>"
$SecurePassword = $key | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $clientID, $SecurePassword
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred -Tenant "<Tenant ID>" -ServicePrincipal;
$disks=Get-AzureRmDisk | Select Name,Tags,Id,Location,ResourceGroupName ; 
foreach($disk in $disks) { foreach($tag in $disk.Tags) { if($tag.Snapshot -eq 'True') {$snapshotconfig = New-AzureRmSnapshotConfig -SourceUri $disk.Id -CreateOption Copy -Location $disk.Location -AccountType PremiumLRS;$SnapshotName=$disk.Name+(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd");New-AzureRmSnapshot -Snapshot $snapshotconfig -SnapshotName $SnapshotName -ResourceGroupName $disk.ResourceGroupName }}}
```

Trying to understand the script, I came up with the question, where are the snapshots stored? In the same managed disk as the VM disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After executing the script, it will create the snapshots that you can check them in the portal, they have the resource type of `Microsoft.Compute/snapshots`.
 Essentially, they should be stored in the blob storage. Navigate to the snapshot in the portal -> Export, then you will find it generates a SAS token of the snapshot like `https://md-nxxxqz.blob.core.windows.net/wxxxxxx0m/abcd?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&si=31b3d91b-51be-4c1c-930e-996f382b8ad9&sig=xxxxxx`. The `md-nxxxqz` is the storage account which stores the snapshots, it is managed by Azure.

Comment: Would it be cheaper to export a snapshot and store it in blob storage?